# Handling transactions in asynchronous MVC actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm wondering what is a good/safe way to handle transactions in an asynchronous MVC action. Specifically MSMQ transactions. I am currently handling them in synchronous actions with an action filter that creates the transaction object in OnActionExecuting, saves it to thread local storage in a static class, and then commits (if appropriate) and destroys the transaction in OnActionExecuted.

I'm guessing the use of TLS here will break down in asynchronous actions.

Aside from passing the transaction instance around to every method call, is there a good/robust way to accomplish this within asynchronous actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine (I haven't test this) that [`System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter(v=vs.118).aspx)'s `OnActionExecuting/OnActionExecuted` are still called at the beginning and at the end of an asynchronous MVC action, much like for a synchronous action.

Provided that's true, just use `CallContext.LogicalSetData` at `OnActionExecuting` and `CallContext.LogicalGetData` at `OnActionExecuted` instead of TLS, as [described by Stephen Cleary in his blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). Your transaction state would flow across threads upon `await` continuations.

Comment: Yes, OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted are still called as before. The Logical CallContext seems to be my guy. Thank you :)